# Convert dates into columns by date ranges and mention exact date for particular ID in R

Tags: r

this data has two columns. One with participant IDs and second with dates. I want to convert the dates to columns and within each column I want exact date of that ID. e.g. t1 march to may 2020, t2 June to sep, t3 oct to dec 2020, t4 jan to feb 2021, t5 march to June 2021. This is a dummy code as in my real data, I have ID as character variable rather than numerical eg CASK-01. Say CASK-01 is repeated six times with different dates, so I want that t1 column has that particular which falls into its range and so on.

```
n <- 6 #in actual data frequencies range from 2-8 or IDs are repeated 2-8 times rather than a fixed number
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:500, each=n), 
                  date=sample(seq(as.Date('2020/03/01'), as.Date('2021/07/30'), by="day"), 12))
```

Here is the structure of my real data:

```
str(df)

tibble [4,347 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id        : chr [1:4347] "CI-001" "CI-002" "CI-003" "CI-004" ...
 $ sampledate: POSIXct[1:4347], format: "2020-03-06" "2020-03-06" "2020-03-06" "2020-03-06" ...
```

I tried to find relevant code but could not find it so far. I could do it manually in excel, in fact I already did that by sorting and then copy-pasting exact date there but I want to do that in R. What do you think? I have posted a dummy result picture as well. Basically first column will be participant id and next five columns are for time, i.e. t1-5 with date ranges. t1 march to may 2020, t2 June to sep, t3 oct to dec 2020, t4 jan to feb 2021, t5 march to June 2021. So dates linked to each participant ID will go into respective time column, t1-5. E.g., if cas-03 has dates: 5 feb 2021 (it’ll show up in t4 column), and 7 and 9 March 2020 (both in t1 but in two row). At the moment each ID is repeated as rows for new linked-date but new table will have IDs repeated in rows only if there’re multiple linked dates in a time column date range. Is it too complicated to do in R. What do think?

[image: This is how it should look]

Recently I tried this code but it said:
Error in filter(., id <= 3) : object 'id' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion

```
# change to your df to have different rep per IDs
df <- df %>% 
  filter(id <= 3) %>% 
  mutate(id = ifelse(id == 3, 2, id))

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(t = paste0("t", row_number())) %>% 
  arrange(t) %>% 
  ungroup()

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = t, values_from = date) %>% 
  head()
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that for each id, there is a value that falls in to each of the t columns? Or could there be multiple values or missing values? The sample example is tricky to work with, as not all the dates fall in to these t buckets for each id

Comment: Yes, for each id there is a date which will fall into either of the next five time columns. No missing value for dates. Only that participants (IDs) were called somewhat randomly, so some participants (IDs) have two appointment (dates) and others have eight (so eight dates) but it will definitely fall in to one of the t columns. I have added str of real data so it should give a better idea. Yeah, it is tricky. Otherwise I would have fixed it myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you have exactly the same number of observations per ID (which is the case in your example since `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% pull(count) %>% unique()` = 6) I would advise you to use the `tidyr` package as follow:

```
library(tidyr)

n <- 6
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:500, each=n), 
                 date=sample(seq(as.Date('2020/03/01'), as.Date('2021/07/30'), by="day"), 12))
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% pull(count) %>% unique()

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(t = paste0("t", row_number())) %>% 
  arrange(t)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = t, values_from = date)
```

Have a look here: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

**EDIT to your comment**

If you do not have the same number of repetition per IDs, that's no big deal. `pivot_wider()` is smart enought and will add NA values in the output, example:

```
# change to your df to have different rep per IDs
df <- df %>% 
  filter(id <= 3) %>% 
  mutate(id = ifelse(id == 3, 2, id))

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(t = paste0("t", row_number())) %>% 
  arrange(t) %>% 
  ungroup()

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = t, values_from = date) %>% 
  head()
```

will return

```
# A tibble: 2 x 13
     id t1         t10        t11        t12        t2         t3         t4         t5         t6         t7         t8        
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
1     1 2021-04-06 NA         NA         NA         2020-10-16 2020-03-17 2021-03-20 2020-11-04 2021-03-22 NA         NA        
2     2 2021-07-26 2021-03-20 2020-11-04 2021-03-22 2021-07-02 2020-03-09 2020-05-13 2021-04-23 2020-04-09 2021-04-06 2020-10-16
# ... with 1 more variable: t9 <date>
```

Comment: Looks good! Does it need a sort in there prior to pivotting? The values don't look to be ascending with the t columns when I tried it out

Comment: Just add ` %>%  arrange(t)` or `  %>%  arrange(desc(t))` prior to pivoting.

Comment: thanks for the comments and suggestions. I have different number of repetitions for an ID. So n = 6 does not work. I added that to make a dummy code. e.g., first three IDs are actually having a frequency of 4, then fourth one 5. I think, the frequency range from 2-8. 

It may help others when they need code for counting repeat IDs:
n_occur <- data.frame(table(df$id))
n_occur[n_occur$Freq > 1,]

Comment: Therefore what kind of table do you expect? A table where its n.cols is the max repetition you have for an ID?

Comment: No but that’s also reasonable. Columns are t1-5. t1 march to may 2020, t2 June to sep, t3 oct to dec 2020, t4 jan to feb 2021, t5 march to June 2021. So Dates linked to each participant ID will go into respective column. Eg if cas-03 has dates: 5 feb 2021 (it’ll show up in t4 column) and 7 and 9 March 2020 (both in t1). Not sure if it’s too complicated to do in R. What do think?

Comment: No but that’s also reasonable. First column is participant id and next five columns are time t1-5 with date ranges. t1 march to may 2020, t2 June to sep, t3 oct to dec 2020, t4 jan to feb 2021, t5 march to June 2021. So Dates linked to each participant ID will go into respective column. Eg if cas-03 has dates: 5 feb 2021 (it’ll show up in t4 column) and 7 and 9 March 2020 (both in t1). At the moment each ID is repeated as rows but new table will have IDs repeated in rows only if there’re multiple linked dates in a time column date range. Is it too complicated to do in R. What do think?

Comment: If the code I gave you does not provide you the answer you expect then I don't understand your need.